# Infinitely many non-equivalent decompositions into irreducibles

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

It is well-known that in an integral domain that is not a UFD, elements can have different decomopositions into irreducibles, that do not just differ by units. But in all examples I know, usually only two such decompositions are given. Is it possible for an element to have infinitely many non-equivalent decompositions?

Comment: Let $(a_n)$ be a sequence of algebraically independent irrational real numbers and let $S=\Bbb{Z}[a_1,\frac2{a_1}, a_2,\frac2{a_2},\ldots]$ then $2$ has infinitely many factorizations in $S$.